# ErrorSortがなぜ、役に立たないのか教えてください。

Tags: アルゴリズム

まず最初に[ErrorSortの記事](http://bugrammer.g.hatena.ne.jp/nisemono_san/20111109/1320788723)の記事を読んでください。

ソートアルゴリズムには一番実装が簡単なソート方法にして、効率の悪さに反して実装例が多い[バブルソート](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88)や要素の値の数が少ないときにはよく使われる[バケットソート](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88)、ネタソートの中ではいちばん有名な[ボゴソート](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9C%E3%82%B4%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88)などがありますが、
エラーソートはなぜ作者がネタソートだと言っているのでしょうか？

パット見役に立ちそうなかかれ方をしているのですが、なぜネタソートなのかがわかりません。
メリットとデメリットも併せて教えてください。

Comment: 一瞥して思い付くのは、マイナス値が含まれていると正しくソートされない場合がある点です(例えば ErrorSort([-1,39,-3,5,-92,0]) など)。

Comment: @metropolis そういえば、記事の実行例にはマイナス値がないですね。

Comment: `"a" * target`と言うのがありますから、`target`、つまり配列の要素が非負の整数でないと動かないというのはmetropolisさんの指摘された通り。また、`target`がとんでも無い大きな整数なら`"a" * target`はとんでも無い長さの文字列を作ります。また`counter`の値が、そのとんでも無い整数の値を超えるまでループし続けます。配列内の最大の整数が1億なら1億回。しかもそのループの1回1回の中でまだ結果に移されていない全要素についてその要素の長さの文字列を作っては捨てるなんてことを繰り返します…。「役に立つ」と言うのが「(所定の制約条件のもとで)正しい結果を返す」と言う意味なら役に立つと言ってもいいでしょうが、まぁ、実用的に使うべきものでは無いでしょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問してみてわかったのですが、`"a" * target`なので非負の整数があると正しくソートされない、
大きな数字だととんでもない長さの文字列が生成され、ループに時間がかかる…。などと言ったことがコメントでデメリットして上げられ、メリットとしては(所定の制約条件のもとで)正しい結果を返すのなら実用性があるというのですが、おそらくですが、[SleepSort](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88#.E3.82.B9.E3.83.AA.E3.83.BC.E3.83.97.E3.82.BD.E3.83.BC.E3.83.88)と同じく役立つのは例題くらいでしょうか。
コメントしてくれた方ありがとうございました。